# Profiling linked-in drivers in Erlang

Tags: erlang, profiling, erlang-driver

How can I profile a linked-in port driver? OTP tools (`fprof`, etc.) apparently only profile Erlang code, and I don't have a C executable file to feed to `gprof`.

Comment: Get it running exercising your driver, flat out. Then take some stackshots (like 10) using **lsstack** or **pstack**. That should show, as percents, how the time is spent. For overall speed, you can just use the run-it-1000-times method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as linked-in port driver is .so library that is dynamically loaded into erl process (on linux) you can run valgrind --tool=callgrind --callgrind-out-file=file.out erl (see other options in docs for callgrind), then execute some tests from erl shell, exit from shell and load file.out in some tool like KCachegrind

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just profile the `erl` executable and then get that to the `gprof` tool? I am pretty sure this is how it is done by the Erlang devs anyway.

Comment: It would be nice to avoid rebuilding OTP, if possible. Of course, other profilers than `gprof` may not require it...